# Why QueryProgressEvent logs from StreamingQueryListener are missing in Spark Structured Streaming job?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am running multiple spark structured streaming jobs and using `onQueryProgress` method from `QueryProgressMetricsListener` class to log `QueryProgressEvent` event. Usually, it works fine and prints the log whenever a micro batch is completed.

But for one of my job, I see that micro batches are progressing as I can see them on SparkUI but this log is not getting printed. I also see below warning message in this job. What could be the  causing this? (My expectation is that `onQueryProgress` will be executed with every new micro batch)

```
2020-06-19 04:09:14 WARN  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.logWarning:66 - Managed memory leak detected; size = 16777216 bytes, TID = 14038
```

Only log that I get from `QueryProgressMetricsListener` is `event : QueryStarted`. There are no logs with `event : QueryProgress`. However, below custom log keeps on getting printed with an increasing batch id.

It is confusing to understand if batches are actually getting processed. My understanding was that Spark process batches sequentially and new batch should appear only when previous one is completed.

```
rates.writeStream
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10000))
    .foreachBatch {
      (_, batchID: Long) =>
        logWarning(s"batchId is : ${batchID}")
        ProcessMain.processCassandra(spark)
    }
    .start()
```

Spark UI snapshots showing batch id 444 and 443
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this happen with this one single query? What if ran alone (without the other queries)? Are all the streaming jobs (queries) part of a single Spark app? Can you include a screenshot of web UI with the progress of the query that you lack updates from?

Comment: It is one single query using rate as source and inside `forEach` loop, getting data from Cassandra, processing and writing back to db. I have edited the post to include snapshots from SparkUI which shows batchId 443 and batchId 444 but surprisingly batch 0 is too.

Comment: Okay. When I mentioned "multiple spark structured streaming jobs" then I meant multiple applications. In each Spark Application, I just just one query. All applications are running fine except this one where I am facing this weird issue where batch0 completion log is missing but batch ids are increasing in spark ui

Comment: No idea why you're getting these batchIds. What's inside `ProcessMain.processCassandra(spark)`? Why do you need `spark` in the `processCassandra`?

Comment: There are many things which I will add to question details in simplified way. But from what I understood we do get a QueryProgress event whenever a micro batch is processed. Is this understanding correct or it is possible that micro batches can progress with new ids and Batch Completed log is not generated?